# encoding issue after pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, pdfbox

I want to extract text in PDF on Java, so I use pdfbox library. PDF file seems to have been written by hwp(korea word edit software) before it was converted to a PDF file.
This is my simple API.

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuestionController {
    private final QuestionParseService questionParseService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> parsePDF() throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(questionParseService.parsePDF());
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class QuestionParseService {
    public String parsePDF() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("filePath");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
        String content = s.getText(document);
        return content;
    }
}
```

This is my PDF file [PDF file](https://workbookquestionimage.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/2019.pdf)

But, the API result of question 1 was

> 1. 
>    
>    ×
>     
>    
>    의 값은? [2점]
>    ①  ②  ③  ④  ⑤ 

How can I get correctly encoded text?

Comment: Do you get what you expect when you copy & paste from Adobe Reader?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr no, I get same bad result when I copy & paste